# How to spawn a process that dies with JVM

Tags: java

**I want to spawn a process that will receive a SIGINT/SIGTERM/SIGKILL when current JVM dies/crashes.**

Note 1: I know there's a difference between SIGINT/SIGTERM/SIGKILL, but I don't know which of these is feasible.

Note 2: I know about shutdown hooks, but I'd like a more reliable solution (hooks only work on graceful JVM shutdowns).

Note 3: currently I'm using a ProcessBuilder to start a long-running foreground process.

Comment: There's no way of having a child process killed automatically as you describe.

Comment: It's not about how you spawn it, it's about how you write it, and the spawning process, to ensure they exit together. You could use a socket or a pipe between them, and have the child process exit when it's closed.

Comment: @niqueco seems like you're right. I found info saying: "When any process having children dies for any reason, its children are reparented to process with PID 1". But I don't understand if this is OS-specific or POSIX behavior.

Comment: It's more than POSIX, it's standard UNIX behavior. If you want a child process to end you either need to terminate from its parent or have some IPC mechanism so that the parent can tell the child to end..